# Drupal module that copies text from uploaded text file to node body

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to find a way to add two ways to create nodes: 1) provide the standard node body textarea for users to type or copy/paste text and 2) allow users to upload text files to be added to the node body field.

The upload process should basically behave like a user just copied the text from the file and pasted it into the node's body textarea.

I am having a hard time trying to find a module that will allow users to upload a text file and have that text get "pasted" into the node's body field. I also only want one place (the body field) to store text. (not one file field for text uploaders and one node body field for "copy and pasters")

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished with current drupal 7 modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago I started a project that do exactly it, but from a PDF.

Unfortunately, we changed our mind and I didn't improve the module, but it works.

Check it out there http://drupal.org/sandbox/yvmarques/1243860

And if you want, don't hesitate to add some patches.